# How to paginate OwnsMany collections?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.2

Consider I'm having a domain entity of User. I want to identify this user by (fingerprint) a set of properties such as IP, email, phone, user-agent. Now since by DDD principles a Fingerprint can't be an entity, so I defined this as a ValueObject. Each time when a user tries to make a transaction I make a lookup for a matching fingerprint to associate a user with the request.

Ef core suggests us using `OwnsMany()` for ValueObjects. My problem is that this collection of owned entities are loaded immediately without any pagination. I may load 100 users per page and each of which may have hundreds of fingerprints because each time IP or user-agent changes I have to create a new one.

**My questions are**

1. Is there a way to paginate those fingerprints? I can't do it, because the repository has a constraint for aggregate roots only.
2. Can I actually use OwnsMany ValueObjects for situations when there are more than 1k objects?
3. If not, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: `OwnsMany()` is not for ValueObjects. It's for Aggregates--graphs of entities that should be loaded and saved atomically.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your whole domain model, so I assume there is a reason why `User` is an entity and contains a collection of `Fingerprints`.

> Each time when a user tries to make a transaction I make a lookup for a matching fingerprint to associate a user with the request.

You should rather not load all records from a database into your application memory. As I understand, what you really need when `User` is making a transaction, are not *all the fingerprints*, but *only the matching one*. A solution would be to properly prepare your object when you are loading it from your database. Do not load all the `Fingerprints`, but only the one you are interested in. You can make another property for that in your User class. Write a Linq query or SQL select in your infrastructure layer.

This solution might cause another problem. Every time you add a new `Fingerprint`, you will have that redundant property in your `User` class that you don't need. When you add new `Fingerprint`, this property will not update automatically. If you do not feel comfortable with it, I would suggest you to seperate your read and write models. You can use Tactical DDD patterns for saving, but probably you don't need them for simple reads.